# How to return Error object if interface expects a MyObject object?

Tags: java, api, rest, object, interface

I have a rest interface generated by a yaml and therefore I cannot modify.
The service expects a `MyObject` object to be returned.

Interface:

```
public interface CheckNameApi {
         
    @POST
    @Path("/check")
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public MyObject checkName(String name) throws ApiException;

}
```

The problem is that in case of an error I should return an error object called `MyError`. How could I do it? The service expects a `MyObject`.

`ApiException` contains a field `Response response`.

**UPDATE**
The MyError class is also generated by the swagger and therefore cannot be modified

Answer (score 0):

Make the `MyError` class extend the `MyObject` class:

```
public class MyError extends MyObject {
    // you can add fields:
    private String errorMessage;
    // you can add constructors and methods
}
```

This way an instance of `MyError` *is a* `MyObject`

Comment: Unfortunately, the MyError class is also generated by the swagger